# Is it possible to group by an object property but have the whole object in the Key?

Tags: linq

Suppose `query` is like so:

```
var query = from x in db.Customers
           join y in db.Orders
           on x.Id Equals y.CustomerId
           where ...
           select new {Customer = x, Order = y}
```

and I want the results grouped by customer:

```
var resultsByCustomer = query.GroupBy(x => x.Customer.Id)
```

This works fine, except that now the grouping Key is the customer id, but I want it to be the whole Customer object, because I want to access other properties of that customer (but not properties I want to group by).

I could do this instead:

```
var resultsByCustomer = query.GroupBy(x => x.Customer)
```

but this doesn't work, because it seems to group by object equality on the Customer class, not the customer id.

Is it possible to group by Customer **Id**, but have the **whole customer object** returned as the Key?

Comment: Do you really need `GroupBy` in such a case? `GroupJoin` looks a better choice to me.

Comment: And if this is Entity Framework with proper **navigation properties**, you'll get all that for free by just querying the `Customers`. Of course if you seek for a general approach and the key you are grouping on is **unique**, then  @StripplingWarrior solution should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Go ahead and group them by the customer ID (with the ID as they Key), and then extract the customer from the first item in the group.

```
var resultsByCustomer = 
    from g in query.GroupBy(x => x.Customer.Id)
    let customer = g.Select(x => x.Customer).FirstOrDefault()
    select ...;
```